# How to apply a Stream reduction (count) to a IntStream and change the return type to "int"

Tags: java, java-stream, reduction

This code won't compile:

```
public int trailingZeroes(int n) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1,n)
            .filter(e -> (e  % 5) == 0)
            .count();
}
```

I noticed this difference in the return types of [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) 
methods:

`int sum()` vs `long count()`

While trying to return an `int` type from the counting operation above,

- I already understand why `count()` returns a long but why have
  `sum()` return a narrower return type than `count()`?
- What would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do in my
  `trailingZeroes` method?

Comment: Isn't this method just doing `(int) n / 5` ?

Comment: @jbx No, not certainly that. It would currently count all the numbers less than N and divisible by 5. Aside: This seems though more like a mathematics problem to count the count of zeroes trailing in a number. But if I remember correctly that used to be something like (n/5 + n/25 + n/125....). Only the OP can share details.

Comment: @nullpointer well what the OP is doing is just taking the numbers in the range that are divisible by 5 without remainder, so dividing it by 5 and dropping the fractional part will give the same result. The range is closed, so the numbers are less than *or equal to* N. (If it wasn't it would have just been `(int) (n - 1) 
/ 5`). And it starts from 1 (it could have even started from 5, would have been same result).

Comment: @jbx true, I get you what you meant now, I really think the name of the method and what it does is misleading here. Have suggested a better implementation in the answer made.

Comment: @nullpointer Yep saw it. Inspired me for a recursive one too :)

Answer (score 3):

The `sum` method returns an `int` because the sum of two ints is an int.

The Javadoc for `count` says that it's equivalent to `mapToLong(e -> 1L).sum()`. You could use that to make your own counting that returns an `int`, like this:

```
return IntStream.rangeClosed(1,n)
        .filter(e -> (e  % 5) == 0)
        .map(e -> 1)
        .sum();
```

Or, because you actually know that your answer will fit in an `int` anyway, just cast it:

```
return (int) IntStream.rangeClosed(1,n)
        .filter(e -> (e  % 5) == 0)
        .count();
```

Answer (score 2):

> count() returns a long but why have sum() return a narrower return
>   type than count()?

From the Javadocs, [`IntStream.count`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#count()) happens to be a special case of reduction

```
return mapToLong(e -> 1L).sum();
```

which is why it returns a `long`. Further [`IntStream.sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum()) is again a special reduction which internally uses [`Integer.sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#sum(int,int))

```
return reduce(0, Integer::sum) // signature of sum being 'int sum(int a, int b)'
```

which is why it returns an `int`.

> What would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do in my
>   trailingZeroes method?

A slight optimization over other solutions, you could use just `map` as :

```
public int trailingZeroes(int n) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
        .map(e -> (e % 5) == 0 ? 1 : 0)
        .sum();
}
```

---

Inferring from the method name, what you should be looking for in your implementation shall be :

```
public int trailingZeroes(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n % 10 == 0) {
        count++;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return count;
}
```

which when represented in Java-9 syntax shall look like :

```
public int trailingZeroes(int n) {
    return (int) IntStream.iterate(n, i -> i % 10 == 0, i -> i / 10).count();
}
```

Comment: Cool use of Java 9 solution with `iterate()`

Answer (score 2):

> I already understand why count() returns a long but why have sum() return a narrower return type than count()?

`sum()` returns the sum of the items in the stream, so the type returned matches the type of the stream. `LongStream.sum()` returns `long`.

The `count()` is not directly related to the type of the objects coming from the stream, and to conform with the rest of the `Stream` classes they chose `long`, the type that represents the largest size. The `count()` method is actually defined at the `Stream` interface level, which is then extended by `BaseStream`, and subsequently by `IntStream`, so the contract of the method signature has to be preserved. (Ideally `count()` should have returned `unsigned`, but Java doesn't support `unsigned`.)

> What would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do in my
>   trailingZeroes method?

Not clear what you are trying to achieve. But I see nothing particularly wrong with it.

If you want it to return `int`, cast the value before returning. I presume you know that the result will always fit safely in an `int` (the result will always be less than `n` which is an `int`), unless you want to change the return type of your method to `long`.

On the other hand can't understand what this method is supposed to be doing. You could have just done:

```
public int trailingZeroes(int n) {
  return n / 5;
}
```

If you are looking for a mathematical way to determine how many trailing `0`s you have in an integer, it would be different. You already have a suggested answer, so taking the liberty to suggest a recursive solution for the fun of it:

```
public int trailingZeroes(int n) {
   return (n % 10 != 0) 
        ? 0 
        : 1 + trailingZeroes(n / 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sum()` returns the sum of elements in this stream and since you use `IntStream`, `sum()` returns int type. Note: `sum()` method for `LongStream` will return `long` type.

To get `int` you can just use casting:

```
return (int)IntStream.rangeClosed(1,n)
            .filter(e -> (e  % 5) == 0)
            .count();
```